# Tab Bar Appearances before ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have upgraded to Xcode 13, I'm now getting the error "Tab Bar Appearances before ios 13". When I click on the error it leads me to a tab bar in a Storyboard without providing additional information.

What could be causing this error?

That's the error:

[image]

That's the tab bar details:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy this file from an older version of Xcode and attempt to run it on Xcode 13? If so, I believe this message is telling you that the Tab Bar is outdated for anything before IOS 13. You will need to rework that piece of code, creating a new Tab Bar.

If not, I would attempt to run the simulator and when it crashes, check the Debug Area and it should give you a little more information.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by deleting the existing Tab Bar from the Storyboard and creating a new one.

Answer (score 6):

Just change the "Builds for" picklist option to "iOS 13.0 and Later" as mine previously was "Deployment Target 11.0" and maybe this is your case too

Photo link here

[image: 1]

Comment: This is the fix worked for me.